# Using struct in a switch statement

Tags: c++, gcc, c++03

I'm trying to create a struct that can be used in a switch statement. I'm using a bunch of wierd compilers like keil armcc and old-fashioned gcc 4.7.1.

That also means c++11 is not an option.

For some time this idea actually worked:

```
struct Test
{
    const int a;

    Test() : a(1) {}

    template<typename T>
    operator T() const;

    operator int() const {return a;}

};

...

Test t;

switch(t)
{
case 1:
    break;
}
```

That compiled just fine. Now I'm trying to move to more recent version of gcc without breaking compatibility with armcc.

But now gcc gives me this:

```
error: ambiguous default type conversion from 'Test'
 switch(t)
         ^
error:   candidate conversions include 'template<class T> Test::operator T() const'
```

And I can't really understand where is the ambiguity since template operator has no body.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Overload resolution doesn't care whether the function has a definition or not. The simplest fix is `switch (static_cast<int>(t))`.

Comment: Using actual cast is my last resort; I would like to avoid it almost at any cost.

Comment: Just get rid of `template<typename T> operator T() const;`? Or do you have other functions elsewhere overloading that operator for a different type?

Comment: In actual code that struct hides enum inside (kinda enum class), so actually I need to allow convertion to enum and disable everything else. If I got read of template operator, there will be implicit convertion between different enums and I don't want that.

Comment: You should consider upgrading your compiler (e.g. to [GCC 5.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) in december 2015). You could download some fresher compiler source from http://gcc.gnu.org/ and build a cross-compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I still have to use old version of armcc.

Comment: Clever use of conversation operators can turn around and bite you later.

Comment: @NeilKirk well, that will be later, right? :) Can you please provide an example?

Comment: See the above question :)

Comment: @NeilKirk what will you suggest than?

Comment: Use an explicit `asInt` etc function

Comment: @NeilKirk that's not better than cast. Why can't I force compiler to do it implicitly? It must be possible, it's c++; we have templates. Anything should be possible :)

Answer (score 2):

You could assign to a temporary int:

```
int n = t;
switch (n) {
   ...
}
```

In the context of `switch (t)`, the compiler considers coercion to integer types including `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`.  By assigning to a variable of type `int`, we <strike>collapse the wave function</strike> force it to pick the conversion we want, and there's no ambiguity when we get to the `switch`.

You should also seriously consider making your template conversion operator `explicit` if you can, as a catch-all conversion can lead to unpleasant surprises.

Comment: Right. So can't we force compiler to pick conversion some other way? I tried overloading conversion (without a body) for all integral types I could remember, but it's still ambigious. (Unfortunately, explicit operators are c++11 feature)

Comment: Sorry, I should have spotted the C++03 tag!  I think the problem is that conversions are defined for *too many* (i.e. >1) integral types, and the compiler can't pick one as 'best'.  If there were only one conversion to integral type, your problem would be solved.

Comment: Isn't there any way to explicitly forbid some conversions? I thought that if I make declaration without definition that will force compiler to choose another realisation..

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(t)
{
case 1:
    break;
}
```

Here the compiler doesn't know what conversion operator to call; it's ambiguous. It could instantiate your templated conversion operator for a few different integral types or call your `int` conversion operator. The fact that the templated conversion operator function is undefined doesn't matter to overload resolution.

The simplest solution is to use `switch (static_cast<int>(t))`.

Comment: Using actual cast is my last resort; I would like to avoid it almost at any cost.

Comment: `int n=t; switch (n) {...}` ?

Comment: I don't understand, why int n=t works and switch doesn't!

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer, with explanation.